# Use index to subset an array in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, subset

I am new to apps script (was a Matlab user before). I am trying to subset an array "names" based on the value of another array "index". Both arrays have the same length:

```
names = [["name1"], ["name2"], ["name3"], ["name4"], ["name5"],["name6"],["name7"],["name8"],["name9"],["name10"]];
index = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1];
```

I want to subset array "names" to just pick up the names where the "index" has a value of 1. I wrote:

```
var subsetNames = names[index];
```

in the hope to get "subsetNames" to equal to:

```
[["name3"],["name5"],["name10"]]
```

The code runs but "subsetNames" remains undefined. How can I modify the code to achieve the subsetting? thanks.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Sample script:

```
var names = [["name1"], ["name2"], ["name3"], ["name4"], ["name5"], ["name6"], ["name7"], ["name8"], ["name9"], ["name10"]];
var index = [0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]; 
var subsetNames = names.filter(function(e, i) {return index[i] == 1}); // [["name3"],["name5"],["name10"]]
```

#### Note:

- This script supposes that the array lengths of both `names` and `index` are the same.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)